# Image preprocessing before feeding into Deep learning algorithm

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I am developing an image segmentation algorithm, I used Deeplabv3+ to train a model, which performs fine. The question is if I can improve its performance. I would like to know if there is preprocessing methods to use before feeding the image.
I want to detect the charging connector, as depicted in the image:
[image]

I can detect it without any problem. But just looking for some improvements if exist.

Comment: how does the original image look like?

Comment: the image I have uploaded is original image but there will be some different light conditions implemented (dark, bright etc.). But these are environmental conditions. I just wanted to know if there is standard methods etc. to improve the image quality to get better results from DL model